# How to make dojo datagrid to have editable row data, sortable and pagination

Tags: php, mysql, json, dojo, dojox.grid

I have a dojo datagrid with datastore of json type. I have already accomplished to display data fetched from mysql database. What I would like to do is to allow pagination, make row data editable and update the edited data to the database. Here's what I have got so far:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @import "dojoroot/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css";
    @import "dojoroot/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
    @import "dojoroot/dojox/grid/enhanced/resources/claro/EnhancedGrid.css";
    @import "dojoroot/dojox/grid/enhanced/resources/EnhancedGrid_rtl.css";

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dojoroot/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true, isDebug: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

require(["dojo/store/JsonRest"], function(JsonRest){
    myStore = new JsonRest({target:"jsonExample.php"});
});
require([
"dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid",
"dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Pagination",
"dojo/data/ObjectStore",
"dojo/domReady!",
"dijit/form/Form"
], function(DataGrid, ObjectStore){
grid = new DataGrid({
store: dataStore = ObjectStore({objectStore: myStore}),
editable:true,
structure: [
    {name:"ID", field:"writer_id", width: "50px"},
    {name:"Writer's Name", field:"writer_name", width: "200px", editable: true},
    {name:"Writer's Email", field:"writer_email", width: "200px", editable: true}
],
//declare usage of plugins
plugins: {
    pagination: {
        sizeSwitch: false,
        defaultPageSize: 10
    }
},
}, "target-node-id"); // make sure you have a target HTML element with this id
grid.startup();
});
</script>
```

jsonExample.php to fetch data from mysql and convert the data to json format

```
<?php
$db=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("could not connect to mysql server");
mysql_select_db("demo",$db) or die("could not connect to database");
$query="SELECT * FROM writers";
$resultSet=mysql_query($query,$db);
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($resultSet)){               
    $arr[] = $row;
}
$jsonStr = json_encode($arr);
mysql_close($db);
echo "{$jsonStr}";
?>
```

I get following error in my javascript console
this.option is undefined
this.defaultPage=this.option.defaultPage>=1?parseInt(this.option.defaultPage,10):1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the solution at http://pradipchitrakar.com.np/programming/dojo-grid-php-mysql-with-pagination/ with demo at http://pradipchitrakar.com.np/demos/dojogrid/

Answer (score 1):

To make your grid editable,
You should set your grid layout (structure) column editable, like this:

```
structure: [
    {name:"ID", field:"writer_id", width: "50px"},
    {name:"Writer's Name", field:"writer_name", width: "200px", editable: true, type: dijit.form.TextBox}, //make editable and use input
    {name:"Writer's Email", field:"writer_email", width: "200px", editable: true, type: dijit.form.Textarea} //make editable and use textarea
]
```

To enable pagination, you have to use **dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid** instead of DataGrid and load a plugin named **dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Pagination**.

Then declare the usage of pagination plugin like this:

```
grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
    store: dataStore = ObjectStore({objectStore: myStore}),
    editable:true,
    structure: [
        {name:"ID", field:"writer_id", width: "50px"},
        {name:"Writer's Name", field:"writer_name", width: "200px", editable: true},
        {name:"Writer's Email", field:"writer_email", width: "200px", editable: true}
    ],
    //declare usage of plugins
    plugins: {
        pagination: {
            sizeSwitch: false,
            defaultPageSize: 10
        }
    }
}, "target-node-id")
```

After that, since you are using JsonRestStore, you have to implement the sort and pagination logic at back end using php code.

The sort and page info are passed to backend via request header in the ajax request of the grid. So all you need is to parse the sort and page header and response correct json data of your models. See [this tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/store_driven_grid/) for more examples and details.

Comment: Which to use jsonReststore or something else for such purpose? please look at the updated question, i get error like this.defaultPage=this.option.defaultPage>=1?parseInt(this.option.defaultPage,10):1;

Comment: @PradipChitrakar: my fault. I updated the answer. You shoud use **new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid** instead and remove comma after plugins option

Comment: plugin dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Pagination will paginate the datastore only, i wanted to achieve server side pagination so that i could have small sized datastore, something like select * from table limit 10,20. How can i connect this plugin to perform such action.